# How to show the first value of dropdown list always on JSP for the first time when page is loaded?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I am working on a JSP page and I need to show the selected value of dropdown list on that JSP page always. Below is my example -

```
<p style="font-weight: bold">Limit</p>
<select id="limit" name="limit">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

For the first time when my page is getting loaded, I wanted to show 10 value as selected from the above dropdown list. Now if I select 20 from the above dropdown list and submit the form, I need to show 20 on that dropdown list by maintaining the state of the dropdown list always, so for that I used below code -

```
<%
String limit = request.getParameter("limit");
%>
<script>
document.getElementById("limit").value = '<% out.print(limit); %>';
</script>
```

But somehow, whenever I am loading my page for the first time, I always see blank field infront of `Limit` dropdown box and then if I select `20` from that dropdown list and submit the form again, then I can see `20 selected` in that dropdown list and if I select 50, and submit the form again, then again, I can also see 50 selected in that dropdown list.

The only problem is for the first time when I load the page, it always shows blank field as selected value in the dropdown list which is not what I want, I want to select 10 for the first time automatically whenever the page is loaded first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a "default" assignment in your code, so your value assignment is assigning the value of `limit`, which is presumably null the first time the page loads, to the dropdown. It sounds like this is resulting in a blank option.

You have two options. The first: if one of the existing values should be the default, assign it to `limit` if there is no value to it:

```
<%
String limit = request.getParameter("limit");
limit = (limit == null) ? DEFAULT_VALUE : limit;
%>
```

Alternately, if one of the existing values is not suitable for a default, you should provide an empty alternative in your options list:

```
<select id="limit" name="limit">
    <option value="">-- SELECT ONE --</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

**PLEASE NOTE:** By interpolating the value of `limit` into your page, you are violating a primary rule of web security: Never echo user input onto the page without untainting it. Consider what would happen if include a `script` tag as the value of `limit`...

Answer (score 1):

The first page load does not have the request parameter set.  A simple solution might be:

```
<%
String limit = request.getParameter("limit");
if (limit == null) {
    limit = "10";
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition around your `<script>`:

```
<% if (limit != null) { %>
...
<% } %>
```

Or you can use jquery (it's almost always a good option with javascript), its method of selecting an `<option>` won't produce this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript is cool thing, but you can achieve selection with HTML features look at description of `<option selected ...>` at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

So your JSP can be rewritten:

```
<select id="limit" name="limit">
<option value="10" selected>10</option>
```